# Search StackOverflow from inside of Windows Explorer

Tags: discussion, search, windows-7

**Note: Windows 7 Only**

---

Not sure if you've ever wanted to search SO from Windows Explorer but just in case you have here is a way to do it.

Step 1: Copy this and save it as SO.osdx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:ms-ose="http://schemas.microsoft.com/opensearchext/2009/">
<ShortName>StackOverflow</ShortName>
<Description>Search StackOverflow via Bing using Windows 7 Federated Search</Description>
<Url type="application/rss+xml" template="http://api.bing.com/rss.aspx?source=web&amp;query={searchTerms} site:stackoverflow.com&amp;web.count=50"/>
<Url type="text/html" template="http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}+site:stackoverflow.com"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Step 2: Double click this file and your done.

Anyway I just thought this might be helpful to someone.

Comment: Google just did a link on their home page : they detect if their search engine isn't installed inside windows explorer. If it is not installed, a blue bar appear on the screen : If you click "OK", you can install the google search engine automaticlly in the same way you would have downloaded it from Microsoft. *I'd like to see the same for stackexchange.*